# Error with outlier removal using DataTables

Tags: r, data.table, outliers

I am trying to remove outliers using the following code

```
dat_outlier = dat
setDT(dat_outlier)

for (j in col_names){
  
  dat_outlier[, (j):= ifelse(!dat_outlier[[j]] %in% boxplot.stats(dat_outlier[[j]])$out,dat_outlier[[j]],NA), by=Comparison]
  
}
```

However, I am getting the following error. Please help to figure out the reason and how to correct it.

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dat_outlier, , `:=`((noquote(j)), ifelse(!dat_outlier[[j]] %in%  : 
  Supplied 62 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 9 in column 'CRP'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

The code was generated by modifying the code mentions on [another question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49983128/16857423)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `dat_outlier[[j]]` gives you all the values of the column and not by the group (`Comparison`). You may try using `lapply` -

```
library(data.table)

dat_outlier = dat
setDT(dat_outlier)

dat_outlier[, (j) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x %in% boxplot.stats(dat_outlier[[j]])$out, x, NA)), 
            by = Comparison, .SDcols = col_names]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It definitely removed the error msg. However, it removes values at the same row location as the first column variable. I am new to R and I am clueless about troubleshooting. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I managed to figure out the issue.  '.SDcols = j ' . However, I noticed that the outlier removal is applied considering the whole dataset, not the individual groups :(

Comment: Ohh... I see that you have asked a new question regarding that and already received quite a few responses.

Comment: since your code basically solved the question I have asked, and the question is new, I thought of posting it as a new question. Thanks again for checking. However, I would appreciate it if you can answer this question. Whenever the `dat_outlier` is changed, `dat` (original variable) also changes. Is there a way to overcome this? Thanks

Comment: Use `dat_outlier <- copy(dat)`